# Selecting object(s) by mouse using ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, wpf

I've got a standalone program using ArcGIS Engine, showing a map on the screen like this:

```
AxMapControl _mapControl;  
AxToolbarControl _toolbarControl;

// in constructor: 
_mapControl = new AxMapControl();
_toolbarControl = new AxToolbarControl();  

// in loading: 
_toolbarControl.SetBuddyControl(_mapControl);
_toolbarControl.AddItem("esriControls.ControlsSelectTool");
_mapControl.LoadMxFile(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\TestProject.mxd");
```

The ControlsSelectTool shows up in the tool, but it does not select anything on the map when I click or drag a rectangle. I probably are missing some basic problem here.

Should I use some other way to select objects in a layer or am I just missing some detail here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [ControlsSelectFeaturesTool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ControlsSelectFeaturesToolClass_Class/0016000000nm000000/) it works on features instead of [ControlsSelectTool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ControlsSelectToolClass_Class/0016000000np000000/) that work on graphics.